# Select all different records from one column that have the same value in other coumn

Tags: sql, sqlite, visual-foxpro

I could use some help kind people!

I have three columns in a table called x:

```
ID | Barcode| Description  
1  | 554412 | Bar  
2  | 554412 | Stone  
3  | 554412 | Bar
```

What I need is to select all the Barcodes along with IDs, where the same Barcode has different Descriptions, so in this case it would show me IDs 1 and 2 with Bar and Stone Description.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Why ID's 1 and 2, rather than 2 and 3?

Comment: @SankarRaj You can't get the IDs if you use `Group by`

Comment: @JibinBalachandran Yes you can. You just have to think outside the join

Comment: If you want the barcodes with different description, you shouldn't select IDs since its irrelevant. For description Bar ID can be 1 and 3

Comment: I basically need all the Barcodes that have more than one Description, but I also need to identify on which IDs is this happening.

Comment: Share a sample output of it.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is tagged both SQL and VFP, I will answer thinking in that context. Here is a little extended sample data of your table:

```
Create Cursor myTable (Id I, Barcode c(10), Description c(10))

Insert Into myTable (Id, Barcode, Description) Values (1,'554412', 'Bar')
Insert Into myTable (Id, Barcode, Description) Values (2,'554412', 'Stone')
Insert Into myTable (Id, Barcode, Description) Values (3,'554412', 'Bar')

Insert Into myTable (Id, Barcode, Description) Values (4,'554413', 'Bar1')
Insert Into myTable (Id, Barcode, Description) Values (5,'554413', 'Bar2')
Insert Into myTable (Id, Barcode, Description) Values (6,'554413', 'Bar3')
Insert Into myTable (Id, Barcode, Description) Values (7,'554413', 'Bar3')
Insert Into myTable (Id, Barcode, Description) Values (8,'554413', 'Bar1')
```

With SQL it is really easy to get what you showed like this:

```
Select * From myTable ;
    where Id In ;
    (Select Min(Id) From myTable Group By Barcode, Description)
```

Just for the sake of VFP, another simple trick that doesn't require anything else is to create a unique index:

```
Index on Barcode + Description tag tmp unique
* Browse
```

Answer (score 0):

This shows barcodes that have more than one distinct description, and the associated id's

```
select x.id, b.Barcode, b.Duplicates
from
(
select Barcode, count(distinct Description) as Duplicates
from x
group by Barcode
having count(distinct Description) >1
) b
inner join x
on x.Barcode = b.Barcode
```

Comment: Hello, this one looks quite cool, but instead (or along with) of the count I also need to see the different Descriptions itselves.

Comment: It seems as though you should make an effort to modify his code to work and post updated code instead of complain that JohnHC didn't do enough work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select x1.ID , x1.Barcode from x as x1 , x as x2 where 
x1.Barcode = x2.Barcode and x2.Description != x1.Description
```

This will return rows 1,2 and 3 in your example because they all meet the criteria for "Same barcode has different description."

Rows 1 and 3 will be returned because they both have the same barcode and different description than row 2.

Comment: Ok, this sounds good, but I explained it poorly I think. I basically need all the Barcodes having more than one Description, but in the result I need to see all three columns to see what is the "relationship" between the IDs, if this set of IDs has unified descriptions or not... or would you know what is the other way to show it?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below answer.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
 id int DEFAULT NULL,
 Barcode  nvarchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 Description nvarchar(40) DEFAULT NULL
) --ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of test
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('1', '554412', 'Bar');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('2', '554412', 'Stone');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('3', '554412', 'Bar');


--  If you want to show all ids then use the STUFF() code, so it will return 1,3 for Bar and 2 for Description
SELECT Barcode, Description,
(
SELECT STUFF( (
SELECT ', ' + convert(varchar(10),b.id )
FROM test b
WHERE b.barcode = t.Barcode AND b.Description= t.Description
FOR XML PATH('') 
) , 1, 2, '')) AS Id
FROM dbo.test t
group by Barcode, Description


-- If you just want to display  1 for Bar and 2 for Description then use below code
SELECT Barcode, Description,
(
SELECT TOP 1 b.id 
FROM test b
WHERE b.barcode = t.Barcode AND b.Description= t.Description
) AS Id
FROM dbo.test t
group by Barcode, Description
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question can be tricky coz when you say ***you need is to select all the Barcodes along with IDs, where the same Barcode has different descriptions,*** then resultset could be id 2 and 3 as well. So i have taken a minimum of the id to represent the first match. See below:

```
with tabl (ID , Barcode, Description)
          as ( select 1 , 554412 ,'Bar' from dual
               UNION ALL
                select 2 ,554412 ,'Stone' from dual
               UNION ALL
                select 3 ,554412 ,'Bar' from dual )
select min(a.id) id,a.barcode,a.description 
from tabl a
inner join  tabl b
on a.Barcode = b.Barcode
group by a.barcode,a.description;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this, hope it will address your requirement:

```
CREATE TABLE tmpTwo(ID INT, Barcode INT, DescriptionE VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO tmpTwo VALUES 
(1,554412, 'Bar'),
(2,554412, 'Stone'),
(3,554412, 'Bar'),
(4,554413, 'b'),
(5,554413, 's'),
(6,554413, 'b'),
(7,554414, 'z')

SELECT s.id, s.DescriptionE
FROM tmpTwo s
INNER JOIN(SELECT MAX(u.id) it FROM tmpTwo u
       WHERE u.barcode IN (SELECT v.barcode FROM tmpTwo v 
                         GROUP BY v.barcode 
                         HAVING (COUNT(DISTINCT(v.descriptionE)))>1 )
GROUP BY u.descriptionE) t ON s.id = t.it
```

Output:

```
id  DescriptionE
2   Stone
3   Bar
5   s
6   b
```

FYI, if you change MAX to MIN then you will get the answer with id 1,2,4,5

Answer (score 0):

you need to do a self join

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-self-join/

1st table will be Select * from table

2nd table will be the difference

in mysql I came up with.... no handy mssql to try it out

Table t1
Number of Records: 3

```
col1    col2    col3
1   554412  Bar
2   554412  Stone
3   554412  Bar

SELECT
distinct
pv1.col2,  pv1.col3

from [t1] pv1
join [t1] pv2 on pv1.col1=pv2.col1
```

Result:

```
 Number of Records: 2
    col2    col3
    554412  Bar
    554412  Stone
```

ack, no col1, sorry, been up for 18 hours.... try a right join

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177490(v=sql.105).aspx